# SQL Query to find new or returning customer based on whether the person attended the same event in any previous year

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm using TSQL and looking to write a query for the below problem

I have a list of people attending a list of events that happens every year - For example an event named DevConf, partConf happens every year - listed in the table below

```
    EventName          EventID      ParticipantName 
    2015 DevConf        01            alex
    2015 DevConf        01            bob
    2016 PartConf       02            james
    2016 PartConf       02            Kevin
    2016 DevConf        03            alex
    2016 DevConf        03            Stev
    2017 PartConf       04            adam
    2017 PartConf       04            Kevin
```

I want to identify, if the customer is new or returning based on whether the person attended the same event in a previous year. Example - 'alex' who is attending the 2016 DevConf should be identified as 'Returning' since he attended same event Devconf in the year 2015 (2015 DevConf) and so do 'Kevin' for 2017 PartConf since he attended '2016 PartConf' others should be identified as 'New'. 
This is what I have come up with

```
Select eventName, 
EventId, ParticipantName, 
ReturningOrNew = Partition by eventName like '%DevConf%',
 case when ParticipantName then 'Existing' Else 'New' End
From Table1
```

I'm very new to SQL and any help on this very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'd advise you to create a different table for the participants, then you can create a view with a query that joins both the tables and you perform a GROUP BY event and participant, with a COUNT for events, then on every row, if the COUNT is greater than 1 then its a returning customer, otherwise he is new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `row_number()` for this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by eventName, participantName order by year) > 1
             then 'returning' else 'New'
        end)
from t;
```

Note:  This interprets "a previous year" as *any* previous year, not just one year before.

Comment: Thank you.. Ideally I'm looking for 'any previous' year. But The event name here differs.. For example the same event DevConf which happened on 2015 is '2015 DevConf' and which happened on 2016 is recorded as '2016 DevConf'.. So I'm not sure if partition by 'EventName' would work

Answer (score 0):

You should really be storing the date of the event in a separate column, so I assume that it is actually the case.

You can use window functions: `lag()` lets you recover the *previous* year a participant attended a given event (if any), which you can compare to the current year to compute the status.

```
select
    t.*,
    case when lag(eventYear) over(partition by eventName, participantName order by eventYear) = eventYear + 1
        then 'Returning'
        else 'New'
    end status
from mytable t
```

Comment: The event name here differs.. For example the same event DevConf which happened on 2015 is '2015 DevConf' and which happened on 2016 is recorded as '2016 DevConf'.. So I'm not sure if partition by 'EventName' would work.. Is there a way to eliminate first 4 characters and have the query consider only the string when partitioning

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way your data is stored, you'll unfortunately need to search using the string event names to see if someone has ever attended the event before. I'd start with a CTE to get a list of events and participants then go from there.

```
;WITH cte_conf_Id AS (
select 
     ParticipantName,
     CASE WHEN EventName LIKE "%DevConf" THEN "DevConf" ELSE null AS ConfName
     ...
)
```

And then you can join to your existing table to go from there. But I'd be thinking about how to structure this better. Ideally you would have a unique ID for each type of conference (So every DevConf is 101, every PartConf is 102, etc.) and then it would be much easier.

Comment: It is a good Idea.. I'm just wondering if manually converting every event name is efficient since there are 20+ events..